# How it should code in OpenCV 2.4 or OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to change this lines of code it original coded in opecv2.3 version

```
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor > extractor(new SurfDescriptorExtractor());//  extractor;
        new OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor(
            Ptr<DescriptorExtractor>(new SiftDescriptorExtractor())
            )
        );
```

convert to openCV2.4 or OpenCV3.0.

Is anyone understand how i should code this ? Appreciated if you can share your guide. Thanks

Comment: Did you even try with OpenCV 2.4? If so, what was the error? All these [things](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html) are in the OpenCV 2.4.11.

Comment: Yes i had tried Opencv2.4, when i compile in Netbean 8.0, it had 2 errors show : 1) unknown type name 'SurfDescriptorExtractor()'; did you means DescriptorExtrator? 2) unknown type name 'OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor' . Since this code is build using opencv2.3, Thats i wonder is it differ declaration in open2.4?

Comment: Do you `#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>` ?